# Генерацией чисел определенной длины

Tags: c#

Скажите, вот есть такой класс `Random`, я пытался сделать так:

```
 private int Num(int min, int max)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return rnd.Next(min, max);
    }
```

а потом просто вызвать метод и присвоить min и max значения. Но то, что я написал, - это не совсем то, что мне нужно... мне нужно, чтобы числа генерировались ЛЮБЫЕ, но длиной 8 цифр... как такое реализовать?

Comment: Используя данный код вы можете столкнуться с проблемой, когда функция будет генерировать ОДИНАКОВЫЕ цифры.

Answer (score 5):

я вижу это примерно так:

```
Random rand = new Random();
rand.GetIntFixedLength(8)//48049028

public static class RandExtension
{
    public static int GetIntFixedLength(this Random rand, int length)
    {
        length = length > 0 && length < 10 ? length : 1; //на всякий случай
        return rand.Next(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, length-1)),
                         Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(10, length)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

min 1000000, max 99999999